# Alternate row color for long table

Tags: css, colors, row

Is there a way to give alternated colors to a table row if the number of rows is greater than a certain amount?

If I do:

```
tr                {background-color: white;}
tr:nth-child(even){background-color: gray;}
```

then it will give alternate colors irrespective of the number of rows. If I try to limit that to tables with five rows or more and do:

```
tr                {background-color: white;}
tr:nth-child(2n+5){background-color: gray;}
```

then, as expected, short tables will not be altered, but the first four rows in a long table will not be altered either.

Comment: If you are using php to generate your rows, than while generating them you can count your rows and if it is the fifth row(and greater) you want to have a different color, add another class to it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `nth:child()` use `nth-of-type()` which is a better thing here, say if any dynamic element generates between the a tag, your selector will break. Basic demo using `nth:type` http://jsfiddle.net/FKZtn/22/

Comment: What kind of demo have you given? It should be a table and at least it should have more than 5 rows, then the style will be applied. If commenting out the rows so that the number of rows is less than or equal to 5, then the style won't be applied.